# How to write a double to char function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function to map 1-27 to a-z and blank accordingly. 
For instance, double2char([1 27 26 1]) should give should give 'a za'.

Here is my code:

```
function char_array = double2char(double_array)
if double_array = 27
   char_array = char(32)
else char_array = char(double_array+96)
end
```

I am completely new to matlab, can someone help to edit my code? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: `letter=sprintf(repmat('%c',1,10),repmat(26+96,1,10))`  assigns `zzzzzzzzzz` to `letter`.

Comment: You probably want to ensure you have integers not doubles too. You could also make a string `T=[char((1:26)+96) ' ']`, then `T(double_array)`.

Comment: You can modify the solution from your previous question - `out = char(input_array+'a'-1); 
out(input_array==27)=' '`.

Comment: The way @Divakar does this is the most common way. The function `char` trunkates the integer value of the double (66.00001 is interpreted as `'B'`, while 65.9999 is interpreted as `'A'`). You may need some guards to make sure the value of the double is within this range it you do not want to use integers.

Comment: There is also a function called `num2str`. Which is slower than `sprintf` but type safe. You should try to google "number to char matlab" or "number to string matlab". You will get plenty of hits.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty but it works... had to use a for loop.

```
function char_array = double2char(double_array)
    char_array='';

    for i=1:1:size(double_array,2),
        if(double_array(i)==27),
            char_array(1,i)=char(32);
        else
            char_array(1,i)=char(double_array(i)+96);
        end
    end
end
```